# Integração HTML e Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou fazendo alguns testes iniciais com javascript, e não estou tendo sucesso ao tentar alterar um parâmetro do meu código HTML. A ideia é que ao clicar o botão "Message", o texto seja atualizado para "New Text!" Segue o código HTML e javascript:

```
<html>
<h1>Javascript</h1>
<h3 id="frase">Default text</h3>
<button id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-primary"> Message </button>
</html>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("frase").innerHTML = "New text!";
  });
});
```

Como devo integrar o que é exibido em HTML com meu código javascript?

Comment: Matheus, bemvindo! A tua pergunta está pouco clara... o código que tens está certo e funciona (vê aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/c56mg0m6/). Qual é o problema que estás a ter para implementar isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisa adicionar a livraria do jQuery e também precisa inserir a TAG `SCRIPT` para o código JavaScript.

Execute o código abaixo e veja o script funcionando.

```html
<html>
<h1>Javascript</h1>
<h3 id="frase">Default text</h3>
<button id="getMessage" class="btn btn-primary"> Message </button>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("frase").innerHTML = "New text!";
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como foi mencionado, você está usando código que se baseia em `jQuery`. Teria que incluí-la primeiro por meio de um tag de `<script/>`.

Sendo já incluído, poderia re-escrever seu código da seguinte forma:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#getMessage').on('click', function(){
    $('#frase').text('New Text!');
  });
});
</script>
```

A diferença aqui é o seguinte:

- `$(function(){})` é um shortcut por `document.ready`
- Já que está pegando pelo `id` do `#getMessage`, pode fazer o mesmo no `#frase`
- `$('#frase').text()` troca o texto que está dentro. Se for colocar HTML mesmo (e.g. `<span>Algo</span>`), usaria `$('#frase').html()`